# Variable Size Array through Keyboard Input Verification

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, codeblocks

I know this question has been asked many times before. But everything I went through indicated it is not possible to declare a variable size array at run time unless we use pointers or vectors. But I am always able to take the array size input in a variable(say n) from user and then declare a array of size n. It never gives any warning or error in codeblocks ,vs code or for that matter any coding website.

```
   int n;
   cin>>n;

   int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];

    }
```

My this code always works, but i don't understand How!!!!
[image: Here is my Build message]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It works because the compiler you are using supports [VLAs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) as an extension. VLAs are not part of the portable C++.

Comment: @Ron - IMHO, you should expand your comment in an answer

Comment: *t never gives any warning or error in codeblocks ,vs code or for that matter any coding website.* -- Try Visual Studio using Visual C++, and you will see the error.  [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/rgPRvU)

Comment: @max66 Appreciate it. There seems to be a duplicate already.